# How to open next screen on Right Button click of navigation drawer in react-native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, drawer

I want to open new screen on right click of navigation drawer in `react-native.`
on Login `submit` button, I have called following code:

**Login.js**

```
this.props.navigator.push({
          id: 'FirstScreen',
          title: 'First Screen',
          iconRight: 'map',
          rightPress: this.onPress, // method to redirect to second screen
          rightText: 'list',
          passProps: {
              api_token: this.state.login_token
            }
        });

//navigate to second screen
 onPress() {
  this.props.navigator.push({
        id: "SecondScreen",
        title: 'Second Screen',
  });
}
```

but I am getting error on this line.

```
this.props.navigator.push({
            id: "SecondScreen",
            title: 'Second Screen',
      });
```

**Getting these errors:**

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')
>
> Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigator')

**App.js**

```
  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
        navigator.navigate = this.navigate;
            switch (route.id) {
                case ‘Login’:
                    return ( <Login navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />);
                case ‘FirstScreen’:
                    return ( <FirstScreen navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />);
                case 'SecondScreen':
                    return ( <SecondScreen navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />);
            }
        }
```

**Navigation.js**

```
module.exports = function (scene) {
    var componentMap = {
        'Login': {
            title: 'Login',
            id: 'Login'
        },
        'FirstScreen': {
            title: 'First Screen',
            id: 'FirstScreen'
        },
        'SecondScreen': {
            title: 'Second Screen',
            id: 'SecondScreen'
        }
    }

    return componentMap[scene];
}
```

Comment: Did you register your Second screen? Not sure how you do your navigation but you can have a look at one of my other [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928565/this2-props-navigator-push-is-not-a-function/39958933#39958933) on how to do the navigation maybe it will help you fix your problem.

Comment: @Lian van der Vyver: Yes. I have registered my second screen in `App.js` as follows:                  `return ( <SecondScreen navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />);`

Comment: What is your Id on that registered screen?

Comment: `id: 'SecondScreen'` this is registered for Second Screen

Comment: Getting these errors:


`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')`  

`Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')`

Comment: Okay it looks like your properties is nog passing trough so it can't find your navigator. If you looked a the answer that I provided in the first comment. I got the same error and for me to fix it I did this `return <LoginScreen {...this.props}/>`. Sorry I will need to see more of your code to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change `this.onPress` method in navigator as follows and remove line contains `rightPress`:

**Login.js**

```
this.props.navigator.push({
       id: 'FirstScreen',
          title: 'First Screen',
          iconRight: 'map',
          rightText: 'list',
          passProps: {
              api_token: this.state.login_token
            }
          });
          onPress: () => {
            this.props.navigator.push({
                id: "SecondScreen",
                title: 'Second Screen',
                iconRight: 'map',
                passProps: {
                    api_token: this.state.login_token,
                    username: this.state.username
                },

              });
           }
        });
```