# Getting Error while Navigating to another screen through Right button of navigation drawer in react-native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, navigator

[image]

I am getting this error while clicking on right button of navigation drawer.

```
this.props.navigator.push({
            id: "ListScreen",
            title: 'List Screen',
      });
```

Comment: You might have the same problem as this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928565/this2-props-navigator-push-is-not-a-function/39958933#39958933). Let me know if you don't have the same problem :)

Comment: I have used as follows `return ( < ListScreen navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />);`

Comment: But if I am keeping as it is `{...route.passProps}` then why I am getting error as **Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator')**