# React Native, Android, undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push') with TouchableHighlight

Tags: android, react-native

iam new in react native this is my first project in it , my problem is when i tried to start another screen into react native i got this error 
:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigator.push')
i dont know why becuse i dont have any experience with react native
this is my code , if anyone have idea !

```
    class loginApp extends Component {
  render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                     Welcome Sign Up Here
                </Text>
                <View>

                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Name"
                        style={styles.formInput}
                         />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Password"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        style={styles.formInput}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                        placeholder="UserName"
                        style={styles.formInput}
                         />
                           <TextInput
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={styles.formInput}
                         />
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}  style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>        
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    onPress()  {
  this.props.navigator.push({
     title: "Secure Page",
     component: SecureView,
  });
}; 
};
```

Comment: This is a posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928565/this2-props-navigator-push-is-not-a-function/39958933?noredirect=1#comment67436731_39958933

Comment: no please this another case !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `props` doesn't contains `navigator` object. Make sure you are supplying `navigator` object when you make an instance of `loginApp`. You can make sure you have passed `navigator` with the following code:

```
class loginApp extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    console.log(props.navigator) // <- this will print in console if you are passing a navigator object.
  }

  ...
}
```